# special characters in dump file

Tags: mysql

When I take the mysqldump, I get the sql statements like the following. And there is no issue.

```
INSERT INTO `route_s` VALUES (120,3,'AKJ','AKLU',27,'O-',63.0,63.0,0.0,11,'','MHR','N','Y','Y','');
```

There are times when I get something like following (note the carriage return \r at the end)

```
INSERT INTO `route_s` VALUES (713497,29195,'NVS','NEVA',1,'OO',0.0,0.0,0.0,1,'','MHR','N','Y','Y','\r');
```

How do I avoid getting this (and other) special characters in the dump file?

I am using Linux and -r (raw file) option does not work.

Comment: If the field contains that data, what would you like for the dumpfile to contain?

Comment: I will like the dumpfile to be clean. This carriage return seems to have issues while porting data. And yes, this is a wrongly entered data by the user.

Comment: You could update the table before dumping.

Comment: "*issues while porting data*" - why not work on fixing those, instead of stripping (potentially meaningful) "special characters" from your data?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Thank you for these extremely helpful links in the comment. This issue has been resolved.